# Google cloud print destinations spinner spinning for a long time

Tags: google-chrome, printing, cloud

Every time I print in Chrome windows X64 v.71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) I am seeing a spinner next to print destinations that can take upwards of 60 seconds before I can print.  I do not really use cloud print, but is this typical?  Any way to speed this up?